# Run n processes at the same time

Tags: c, linux, process

I'm running three processes at the same time. And I would like to know how can I put this code inside a for loop, to create multiple processes (not only 3), and execute all the processes at the same time:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){

    int pid1 = fork();

    if(pid1 == 0){
        //Code process 1
    }

    int pid2 = fork();

    if(pid2 == 0){
        //Code process 2
    }

    int pid3 = fork();

    if(pid3 == 0){
        //Code process 3
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unless you're doing this just to learn how to do it, C is the wrong tool for this job.  Just write each process as a completely separate process and run them via a shell script.

Comment: You have replicated some code three times, and simply adapted variable names by incrementing a digit that is in the name in the copies.  Converting that repeated logic into a loop is trivial.